# Is it good to use setattr inside @classmethod decorator in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a class that is being called from several functions with varying input parameters.

```
class demo:   
     def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar
     @classmethod
     def fromdict(cls, dict):
        for key, val in dict.values():
            setattr(cls, key, val)
        return cls(foo1, bar1)
```

There are two methods to instantiate the class. In the first method, I have control on the attribute name. while in the second case, I don't know the names beforehand. Is there a way to get the names before we perform some operation. Or Is there a way to know which method was used to instantiate the class.

I know that in classmethod decorator it calls the original **init** of the class.

Comment: Is the intent to retrieve appropriate values from the dict to pass to `demo.__init__`, something like `return cls(foo=dict['foo'], bar=dict['bar'])`? It's not clear why you are setting class attributes based on the dict, nor where `foo1` and `bar1` come from.

Comment: It is meant to use with two fix attributes and several variable attributes with variable names. It means that any dictionary pass to the class methods must have at least two attributes required for the __init__. Other than that user may supply any number of key value pairs. But, I can do some manipulation so that I am aware of the list of attributes. For that requirement, I want to know the attributes beforehand.

Comment: You are creating class attributes instead of instance attributes... is that on purpose?

Comment: Looking at the list doesn't mean you have to create class attributes. The key is that your class must have some names it *expects* the `dict` to include, in which case you can simply access them as in my first comment. You can't take an arbitrary dict and expect to figure out which keys indicate the values to use for the `foo` and `bar` arguments.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the direction. It will help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

From the example provided there doesn't appear to be any reason you need the variables set at the class scope. If that assumption is correct, the simple solution would be to set the dictionary items directly (and use optional kwargs in **init**).

```
class demo:   
 def __init__(self, foo=None, bar=None):
    self.foo = foo
    self.bar = bar

 @classmethod
 def fromdict(cls, dct):
    # create instance
    obj = cls()
    # vars grants direct access to the underlying __dict__
    # so you can arbitrarily assign new variables
    return vars(obj).update(dct)
```

The question isn't totally clear however, so please be a little more specific with what you're trying to achieve and I'll update.

small note: avoid using `dict` as a variable name as it is a builtin type in python. Calling dict() creates a dictionary.

also, in your for loop:

```
for key, val in dict.values()
```

What you want here is `for key, val in dct.items()`